# Python3 requests ignore SSL

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, curl

While consuming a private https API, I manage to ignore ssl/tls error with google chrome and also with powershell if I first write that :

```
#Bypass certificate
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3"
add-type @"
   using System.Net;
   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
   public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
      public bool CheckValidationResult(
      ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
      WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
      return true;
   }
}
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

However with curl --insecure I get SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL , and with python3 requests.get(url, verify=False) there is an error on the do_handshake method from ssl.py. Below the python error :

```
  File "C:\Users\mdr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mdr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mdr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mdr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mdr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
PS C:\Users\mdr\Documents\git_windows\miscellaneous>
```

The certificate sent by the API is a selfsigned outdated certificate, it is not even a web certificate signed by a selfsigned certificate.

I manage to succesfully retrieve the XML file from the API with wget :
wget --no-check-certificate  "https://10.17.64.102:8085/?StationList"

Comment: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL is unrelated to certificate validation, which means that trying to ignore certificate validation will not help. The same is likely true with the python code, although you only mention an unspecific *"error"* without giving details of the error.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for your answer. I edited my question to add python error.